web3.jsでSmartcontractのdeployをしたいが、署名のところでエラーになります
なお、同じSmartcontractはWeb3.pyでのDeployは成功しています。
nodejsで実装する必要があり、置き換えようとしているのですがエラーが出ており、解決のご協力いただけるとありがたいです。
Web3.js(Ver.4.11)でdeployをしようとしています。
ネットワークはethereumではなく、japan open chainを使用しています。
windows11でwslは使用していません。
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity >0.5.0;

contract Coin {
    string public symbol;

    constructor (string memory _symbol) {
        symbol = _symbol;
    }

    function setSymbol(string memory _symbol) public {
        symbol = _symbol;
    }

    function getSymbol() view public returns (string memory) {
        return symbol;
    }
}

自作classのcompileとdeployのところを抜粋します。
足りない指摘いただければ追記します。
  #compile = (sourceFilePath, contractName) => {
    const solc = require('solc');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const pas = require('path');
    const fileName = pas.basename(sourceFilePath);
    const sourceCode = fs.readFileSync(sourceFilePath, 'utf8');
    const input = {
      language: 'Solidity',
      sources: {
        [fileName]: {
          content: sourceCode,
        },
      },
      settings: {
        outputSelection: {
          '*': {
            '*': ['*'],
          },
        },
      },
    };
    const compiledCode = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
    this.bytecode = compiledCode.contracts[fileName][contractName].evm.bytecode.object;
    this.abi = compiledCode.contracts[fileName][contractName].abi;
  }

  #deploy = async (fromAddress, privateKey, symbol) => {
    // this.ethはweb3.eth、this.utilsはweb3.utilsです
    const contract = new this.eth.Contract(this.abi);
    contract.handleRevert = true;
    const contractDeployer = contract.deploy({
      data: '0x' + this.bytecode,
      arguments: [symbol],
    });

    const createTransaction = await this.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
      {
        from: this.utils.toChecksumAddress(fromAddress),
        data: contractDeployer.encodeABI(),
      },
      privateKey
    );

signTransactionを実行したところでエラーになります。
    process["on"]("unhandledRejection", function (reason) { throw reason; });
                                                            ^

InvalidResponseError: Returned error: invalid opcode: PUSH0
    at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Develop\nodejs_22\node_modules\web3-core\lib\commonjs\web3_request_manager.js:281:23)
    at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Develop\nodejs_22\node_modules\web3-core\lib\commonjs\web3_request_manager.js:167:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Develop\nodejs_22\node_modules\web3-core\lib\commonjs\web3_request_manager.js:21:58)      
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  cause: { code: -32000, message: 'invalid opcode: PUSH0' },
  code: 101,
  data: undefined,
  statusCode: undefined,
  request: {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: '22b005ba-27e7-41ff-a869-1a7d47dc80fa',
    method: 'eth_estimateGas',
    params: [
    ...

opcodeのエラーのようですが、pythonではdeploy出来ていたのでsolidityの問題ではないと思っています。
コードが長く抜粋で足りていないかもしれませんが、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

自己解決出来ました。
EVMがdefaultのshanghaiになっているのが問題でした。
parisに変換したら無事通りました。
settingsを以下のようにEVMを変更(追加)しています。
    const input = {
      language: 'Solidity',
      sources: {
        [fileName]: {
          content: sourceCode,
        },
      },
      settings: {
        evmVersion: 'paris',
        outputSelection: {
          '*': {
            '*': ['*'],
          },
        },
      },
    };

Japan Open Chainがshanghaiに対応していないのかもしれません。
見ていただいた方がいれば、ありがとうございました。
